# Wireless-Bridge on a ubuntu 22.04 (netplan) for three QEMU VMs

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu, netplan, wireless-bridge

I do have an apparently trivial, but it is rather an ambitious project.

Wishing to run three `ubuntu 22.04` VMs on my laptop, installing and configuring `kubernetes` for an initial learning phase with the hope to create a new development environment in my team. The host is also an `ubuntu 22.04`.

No issues to create the VMs via a default installation as I now have a single image (qcow2) that I can use to spin up the three VMs. I am struggling with the network configuration though, and frankly speaking this is not my main area of expertise.

I've extensively read the official documentation including several online resources, and it seems like the **bridge** is the best viable solution for my configuration. The three machines need to be able to talk each other and also capable to fetch assets from internet.

Ubuntu 22.04 is also using **netplan** as a new network configuration interface and here is probably another place where i am miserably failing due to lack of expertise and understanding.

In short ...

1. With this configuration I can't get the VM to talk each other,they are isolated themselves:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-name test1 \
-m 2048 \
-drive file=ubuntu-22.04.03-202402202411.qcow2,index=0,media=disk,format=qcow2 \
-netdev user,id=net0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0
```

2. On my local machine, which is also running `ubuntu 22.04`, I've tried to play with netplan using the below configuration on a dedicated `yaml` file under `/etc/netplan`:

```
network:
  wifis:
    wlp0s20f3:
      access-points:
        "<sid>":
          password: "<pwd>"
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
  bridges:
    brqemu:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - wlp0s20f3
      optional: true
```

then ran `netplan --debug try` and `netplan --debug apply`. An additional attempt was made also by running `netplan generate`.

The `brctl show` command shows the new `bridge` but does not seem to work at all, I assume there should be some interface attached there:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
brqemu      8000.7eb8cd3be115   yes     
virbr0      8000.525400d83776   yes     
virbr1      8000.5254002204df   yes
```

Then went again through more docs in the QEMU website, and confused where I should use a different network device, or perhaps a possibility to manage the configuration with ad hoc routing rules from the host machine and avoid the bridge, which turn to be a bit tricky on a laptop behind wifi connections.

Has anyone a working netplan configuration to create the bridge on ubuntu 22.04 ? No physical cable, only via wifi connection.

Can you suggest a better network configuration for QEMU to be able to spin up the three machines and proceed with the k8s configuration?

I hope it makes sense for anyone willing to read and help!

Thank you!